# How to detect POST redirect in Iframe after integrated payment flow completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

I'm integrating with a payment provider on my website in React.js, and I have a 3rd party payment page URL where the customer is redirected upon clicking "Pay now". The 3rd party provider have configured the returnUrl after payment submitted, a POST request hitting my backend controller who then redirects customer back to my Checkout page with error or Thank you-page

This is working fine as a redirect flow, but the 3rd party provider suggests it's also fine to open the payment page URL in an Iframe so that the customer remains on my website. But once the payment is completed inside my Iframe, the returnUrl is also triggered inside my Iframe and render my checkout page/thank you-page in there.

What would be the correct way of knowing the payment flow is completed from the Frontend side? The only working solution I have at the moment is the following, which feels a bit hacky:

```
const listenToIframeRedirect = (): void => {
    iframeLoad += 1
    if (iframeLoad > 1) {
        // call my backend to check status of payment
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone with experience of a payment flow in Iframe could share the full data flow, Frontend - Backend - Payment provider.

Comment: _"the returnUrl is also triggered inside my Iframe"_ - so make that not directly show your thank you page, but have it only return a tiny JavaScript snippet, that redirects the _parent_ window of the iframe to your thank you page.